# Core Graphics image blending doesn't release memory

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-management, core-graphics

I am blending two images with the following code:

```
+ (UIImage *)xxx_blendedImageWithFirstImage:(UIImage *)image
                                secondImage:(UIImage *)secondImage
                            renderedInFrame:(CGRect)frame
                                      alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);
    
    [image drawInRect:frame];
    [secondImage drawInRect:frame blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];
    
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    
    return newImage;
}
```

This code is called in an `IBAction` for a `UISlider`, so that it is called on every slider position change. This is the memory footprint for this code:

[image: Memory footprint]

It takes 230 MB and then fails due to memory pressure.

How to make this code working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding `@autoreleasepool`:

```
+ (UIImage *)xxx_blendedImageWithFirstImage:(UIImage *)image
                                secondImage:(UIImage *)secondImage
                            renderedInFrame:(CGRect)frame
                                      alpha:(CGFloat)alpha {
    UIImage *newImage = nil;
    @autoreleasepool {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, NO, UIScreen.mainScreen.scale);

        [image drawInRect:frame];
        [secondImage drawInRect:frame blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:alpha];

        newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
    return newImage;
}
```

Maybe, there should be some manual release, however now the memory footprint looks like:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Perform this action on background thread, if you have connected this IBAction with `Value Changed` event in xib. `Make sure do all UI changes on main thread`.

Otherwise connect this IBAction with `Touch Up Inside` event. After this method will call, when you leave the slider for one time in one drag. (not for all dragging values)

Hope it will solve your problem

Comment: In iOS 4 and later, you may call this function from any thread of your app. [Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions)

Comment: @pawan Yes it is working on main thread, but the issue is with memory